# Preview images in Portrait screen mode issues in Samsung Glaxy NoteII for Android apps

Tags: android, camera, preview

I am having problem with the preview of the captured pictures.

I have set up the ImageView to preview the image in the xml file. Once the picture is taken, i get a save or discard preview of the taken images.

I can preview the captured photo in the ImageView only when i capture the photo in Landscape screen mode and declare the orientation as android:screenOrientation="portrait" in the Android Manifest file. I can preview the image in the Image View in portrait view!
Screen shot:
Landscape Screen mode:
[image: Before previewing]

[image: preview]

But, once the photo is captured in portrait screen mode, after clicking on the 'Save' button, it does not display any preview on the ImageView.

Screen shot: 
[image: Before Preview]
[image: On preview]

I am using Samsung Glaxy Note II.

I have tried this code:

```
public  Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {//you can provide file path here 
    int orientation;
    try {
        if (path == null) {
            return null;
        }
        // decode image size 
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
        scale++;
        }
        // decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        Bitmap bitmap = bm;

        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);

        orientation = exif
                .getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 1);

        Log.e("ExifInteface .........", "rotation ="+orientation);

       //exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90, 90);

        Log.e("orientation", "" + orientation);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        if ((orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)) {
            m.postRotate(180);
       //m.postScale((float) bm.getWidth(), (float) bm.getHeight());
            // if(m.preRotate(90)){
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), m, true);
            return bitmap;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            m.postRotate(90); 
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), m, true);
            return bitmap;
        }
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            m.postRotate(270);
            Log.e("in orientation", "" + orientation);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                    bm.getHeight(), m, true);
            return bitmap;
        } 
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

My xml file to display preview and to do other functions:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivReturnedPics"
 android:layout_width="168dp"
android:layout_height="168dp" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/testsh"
android:padding="3dp" />
```

**I am using the code:**
decodeFile(filePath);
ivv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me taken from the Hack Book from facebook

```
public static Bitmap scaleImage(final Context context, final Uri photoUri)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    final BitmapFactory.Options dbo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    dbo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, dbo);
    is.close();
    int rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight;
    final int orientation = getOrientation(context, photoUri);
    if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outHeight;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outWidth;
    } else {
        rotatedWidth = dbo.outWidth;
        rotatedHeight = dbo.outHeight;
    }
    Bitmap srcBitmap;
    is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
    if (rotatedWidth > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION
            || rotatedHeight > MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION) {
        final float widthRatio = ((float) rotatedWidth)
                / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        final float heightRatio = ((float) rotatedHeight)
                / ((float) MAX_IMAGE_DIMENSION);
        final float maxRatio = Math.max(widthRatio, heightRatio);
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = (int) maxRatio;
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    } else {
        srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    }
    is.close();
    if (orientation > 0) {
        final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(orientation);

        srcBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0,
                srcBitmap.getWidth(), srcBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
    final String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(photoUri);
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if (type.equals("image/png")) {
        srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    } else if (type.equals("image/jpg") || type.equals("image/jpeg")) {
        srcBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    }
    final byte[] bMapArray = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bMapArray, 0, bMapArray.length);
}
public static int getOrientation(final Context context, final Uri photoUri) {
    /* it's on the external media. */
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
            new String[] { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() != 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

in your `onActivityResult` just call `scaleImage(this,YOU_URI);` and `imageView.setImageBitmap(Your_Bitmap);`

Comment: Hi I'mNoBody, thanks for your reply. I am doing it using intent. So how will i integrate your logic in my code? I have seen your sample implementation using scaleImage(this,YOU_URI); Here, you have used Context context. Without context how can i implement my logic. Because i can see you have context objects in your logic. In my code when users click on the take a photo button, i am doing it using intent. For example: case R.id.ibTakePic:
   i= new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(i, camreaData);
   break;

Comment: and on activity result i am doing this: protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){ ...................if (filePath != null) {
    decodeFile(filePath);
   } else {
    bmp = null;
   }

Comment: owh you are using it for camera intent ? will  it require different method as for samsung devices it requires workaround method from 3.2 to 2.2. if your application will work on 2.3.x then you'll have to use it. just reply me i'll post the code.

Comment: Hi I'mNoBody. thanks for your reply. sorry for late response. yes if you could show me your example i may figure out my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

first:

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

second the hard work. `onActivityResult`

```
 (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                    imageFileUri = intent.getData();
                    bmp = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                    view.setImageBitmap(bmp);       
                    view.setImageBitmap(bmp);// its weird i know but it wont work if not like this :D   

                  if (imageFileUri != null) {  
                        imageFileUri = intent.getData();
                        bmp = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
                        view.setImageBitmap(bmp);       
                      } 
                  else {  
                       // Describe the columns you'd like to have returned.  
                       // Selecting from the Thumbnails location gives you both the  
                       // Thumbnail Image ID, as well as the original image ID  
                      String[] projection = {  
                      MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID, // The columns we wANT  
                      MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,  
                      MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND,  
                      MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA };  
                       String selection = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.KIND + "=" + // Select  
                                    // only        // mini's  
                         MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND;  
                          String sort = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID + " DESC";  
                          // At the moment, this is a bit of a hack, as I'm returning  
                       // ALL images, and just taking the latest one. There is a  
                       // better way to narrow this down I think with a WHERE  
                       // clause which is currently the selection variable  
                          Cursor myCursor = this.managedQuery(  
                       MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
                       projection, selection, null, sort);  
                       long imageId = 0l;  
                       long thumbnailImageId = 0l;  
                       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    String thumbnailPath = "";  
                       try {  
                         myCursor.moveToFirst();  
                         imageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor   .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID));  
                             thumbnailImageId = myCursor.getLong(myCursor   .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID));  
                         thumbnailPath = myCursor  
                      .getString(myCursor    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA));  
                       } finally {  
                         myCursor.close();  
                      }  
                      // Create new Cursor to obtain the file Path for the large  
                      // image  
                      String[] largeFileProjection = {  
                             MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,  
                       MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };  
                      String largeFileSort = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID  
                         + " DESC";  
                      myCursor = this.managedQuery(  
                       MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
                       largeFileProjection, null, null, largeFileSort);  
                       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    String largeImagePath = "";  
                      try {  
                        myCursor.moveToFirst();  
                           // This will actually give yo uthe file path location of  
                        // the image.  
                        largeImagePath = myCursor  
                       .getString(myCursor  
                      .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));  
                      } finally {  
                      myCursor.close();  
                      }  
                      // These are the two URI's you'll be interested in. They  
                      // give you a handle to the actual images  
                      Uri uriLargeImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(  
                      MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
                      String.valueOf(imageId));  
                      @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Uri uriThumbnailImage = Uri.withAppendedPath(  
                      MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,  
                       String.valueOf(thumbnailImageId));  
                      imageFileUri = uriLargeImage;  
                      }  
                      }
```

Comment: I'mNoBody..thanks. but still it is not the solution i am looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug for Note 2 devices. The latest Note 3 does not have this bug.

Thanks guys for your contribution.